# Extracting HTML between tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract all HTML between specific HTML tags.

```
<html>
<div class="class1">Included Text</div>
[...]
<h1><b>text</b></h1><span>[..]</span><div>[...]</div>
[...]
<span class="class2">
[...]</span>
```

so want to grep all HTML (tags & values) between the `class1` `div` and the `class2` `span`.

```
Included Text
<h1><b>text</b></h1><span>[..]</span><div>[...]</div>
```

Also there are multiple occurrences within the HTML file so I want to match them all. Here is what I mean:

```
<html>
(first occurrence)
<div class="class1">Included Text</div>
[...]
<h1><b>text</b></h1><span>[..]</span><div>[...]</div>
[...]
<span class="class2">
[...]</span>

(2nd occurrence)
<div class="class1">Included Text</div>
[...]
<h1><b>text</b></h1><span>[..]</span><div>[...]</div>
[...]
<span class="class2">
[...]</span>  

(third occurrence)
<div class="class1">Included Text</div>
[...]
<h1><b>text</b></h1><span>[..]</span><div>[...]</div>
[...]
<span class="class2">
[...]</span>  
</html>
```

I've been searching for answers using Beautifulsoup 4. However, all questions/answers are related to extracting values between text, but that is not want I want. I was also wondering if this is even possible with Beautifulsoup or whether I must use regex instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can role your own function using  *bs4* and *itertools.takewhile*

```
h  = """<html>
 <div class="class1">Included Text</div>
[...]
<h1><b>text</b></h1><span>[..]</span><div>[...]</div>
[...]
<span class="class2">
[...]</span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(h)
def get_html_between(start_select, end_tag, cls):
    start = soup.select_one(start_select)
    all_next = start.find_all_next()
    yield "".join(start.contents)
    for t in takewhile(lambda tag: tag.get("name") != end_tag and tag.get("class") != [cls], all_next):
        yield t

for ele in get_html_between("div.class1","div","class2"):
    print(ele)
```

Output:

```
Included Text
<h1><b>text</b></h1>
<b>text</b>
<span>[..]
</span>
<div>[...]</div>
```

To make it a little more flexible, you can pass in the initial tag and a *cond* lambda/function, for multiple class1s just iterate and pass each on:

```
def get_html_between(start_tag, cond):
    yield "".join(start_tag.contents)
    all_next = start_tag.find_all_next()
    for ele in takewhile(cond, all_next):
        yield ele


cond = lambda tag: tag.get("name") != "div" and tag.get("class") != ["class2"]
soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "lxml")
for tag in soup.select("div.class1"):
    for ele in get_html_between(tag, cond):
        print(ele)
```

Using you newest edit:

```
In [15]: cond = lambda tag: tag.get("name") != "div" and tag.get("class") != ["class2"]

In [16]: for tag in soup.select("div.class1"):            
            for ele in get_html_between(tag, cond):
                print(ele)
            print("\n")
   ....:         
Included Text
<h1><b>text</b></h1>
<b>text</b>
<span>[..]</span>
<div>[...]</div>


Included Text
<h1><b>text</b></h1>
<b>text</b>
<span>[..]</span>
<div>[...]</div>


Included Text
<h1><b>text</b></h1>
<b>text</b>
<span>[..]</span>
<div>[...]</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've become closer but I wasn't clear what I ultimately wanted to achieve, my bad.  All I want now is to include text in the first div tag. Also there are multiple occurrences of HTML between the two tags within the HTML file. I want to iterate to them and grep them all.

Comment: Thank you Padraic, I think we are almost there I've edited my question to clarify what I mean with "matching" multiple occurrences.

Comment: @user3030473, the last code block seems to do exactly what you want, how does it not work for you?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The output consisted of multiple lists with elements. I wanted the output to be a single string. I solved this by writing to a file with UTF-8 encoding, then re-opened the file, decoded it as one string in a value.