# How can I find one tag between two other tags?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a document with structure like this:

```
<tag1>some_text_1</tag1>
<tag2>text_1</tag2>
<tag3>....</tag3>
<tag2>text_2</tag2>
<tag1>some_text_2</tag1>
<tag2>text_3</tag2>
...
```

And I need to get all `tag2` instances that are after `tag1` with `some_text_1` and before the next `tag1`.

Comment: do you mean before the next < tag2>text_2</tag2> or before <tag1>some_text_2</tag1> because all the instances  of tag2 before the next tag2 makes no sense. as there will be only one tag2.

Comment: Can tag2 come anywhere after or directly after? Your example input does not really lend itself to your problem description.

Comment: Yes, my bad it should be after tag1 with specified text and before next tag1

Comment: Is it directly after or can come anywhere after?

Answer (score 1):

Your description  *I need to get all tag2 instances that are after tag1 with some_text_1 and before the next tag2.* basically equates to getting the first `tag2` after any tag1 with the text `some_text_`.

So find the `tag1's` with the certain text and check if the next sibling tag is a `tag2`, if it is pull the tag2:

```
html = """<tag1>some_text_1</tag1>
<tag2>text_1</tag2>
<tag3>....</tag3>
<tag2>text_2</tag2>
<tag1>some_text_2</tag1>
<tag2>text_3</tag2>"""


def get_tags_if_preceded_by(soup, tag1, tag2, text):
    for t1 in soup.find_all(tag1, text=text):
        nxt_sib = t1.find_next_sibling()
        if nxt_sib and nxt_sib.name == tag2:
            yield nxt_sib

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

print(list(get_tags_if_preceded_by(soup, "tag1", "tag2", "some_text_1")))
```

If it does not have to be directly after, it actually makes it simpler, you just need to search for a specific `tag2` sibling:

```
def get_tags_if_preceded_by(soup, tag1, tag2, text):
    for t1 in soup.find_all(tag1, text=text):
        nxt_sib = t1.find_next_sibling(t2)
        if nxt_sib:
            yield nxt_sib
```

If you really want to find tags between two tags specifically, you can use the logic in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290588/extracting-html-between-tags/38290786#38290786).

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

html = '''<tag1>some_text_1</tag1>
        <tag2>text_1</tag2>
    <tag3>....</tag3>
    <tag2>text_2</tag2>
    <tag1>some_text_2</tag1>
    <tag2>text_3</tag2>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

def findalltags(tag1,tag2,soup):
    # tag1 is between which tag
    # tag2 get info of which tag
    a = soup.find(tag1)
    lis = []
    while True:
        a = a.find_next()
        if(str(a.name) == tag1):
            break
        elif(str(a.name) == tag2):
            lis.append(a)
    return lis
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print findalltags('tag1','tag2',soup)
```

Hope this will solve the problem but I don't think this is an efficient way. You can use regular expressions if you familiar with them.

Comment: `a.name` is a string, the parens are also not needed.

Comment: we will get it in Unicode I don't know if it can be equal with the string so to avoid it I converted into string

Comment: `u"foo" == "foo"` is going to work fine, if there are non ascii chars in the name then calling str would error.